# Memory efficient statistical distribution module

Tags: perl, statistics

I'd like to analyze some data (say, web-service response times) and get various statistical info, mainly percentiles/quantiles and presence of outstanding values.

I know about [Statistics::Descriptive](https://metacpan.org/module/Statistics::Descriptive), however, I don't want to store all the data in memory. On the other hand, having my results off by a few % would be fine, I only care about huge differences.

So I came up with the following idea: create an array of logarithmic buckets, and count data points landing in each bucket. Having the data spread across 6 orders of magnitude and guaranteed precision of 1% still leaves me with `6 * log 10 / log 1.01 =~ 1400` buckets which is perfectly fine (36 kb of memory, given current Perl's scalar size).

Counting percentiles is simple - just add up bucket counters until `$sum` exceeds `$percentage * $total_count`.

However, before I start writing actual code, I would like to ask which memory efficient statistical modules (for Perl) and algorithms already exist.

I have found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248815/), and there's similar method proposed in one of the answers. Haven't found a ready-made Perl implementation, though.

This is a slightly edited version of this  [Perlmonks question](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1037660).

Comment: Couldn't resist and started out a [github project](https://github.com/dallaylaen/perl-Statistics-Approx-Bucket).

Comment: You can maintain certain statistics in O(1), like min, max, mean, variance.

Comment: @mitchus: Sure! However, I'm interested in percentiles which are not that easy...

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to do that bit in R? :)

Comment: @briandfoy Good point, but I doubt my coworkers would thank me for carrying around R as dependency just because I think rough median is occasionally better than precise mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my search has been unsuccessful so far, I've started a new module [Statistics::Descriptive::LogScale](https://metacpan.org/module/Statistics%3a%3aDescriptive%3a%3aLogScale). Hope it will be helpful.

It generally follows the API of [Statistics::Descriptive::Full](https://metacpan.org/module/Statistics%3a%3aDescriptive), with several minor additions (like added central and standardized moments of arbitrary powers). I also plan to take a much closer look at [Statistics::Descriptive::Weighted](https://metacpan.org/module/Statistics%3a%3aDescriptive%3a%3aWeighted).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Statistics::Descriptive::LogScale;

my $stat = Statistics::Descriptive::LogScale->new ();
while(<>) { 
    $stat->add_data(m/(-?\d+(?:\.\d*))/g);
};

# This can also be done in O(1) memory, precisely
printf "Average: %f +- %f\n", 
    $stat->mean, $stat->standard_deviation;

# This requires storing actual data, or approximating
foreach (0.5, 1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 90, 95, 99, 99.5) {
    printf "Percentile($_): %f\n", $stat->percentile($_);
};
```