# Computing percentiles using a fixed amount of memory

Tags: algorithm, resampling, percentile, streaming-algorithm

I have a stream of int values arriving at a certain rate. Every 5 minutes, I'd like to compute some percentiles from the values, and start over.

The problem: I don't want to waste too much memory, so I'd like to keep only a few KBs for the values. If my buffer does not fill during 5 minutes, I can compute the percentiles perfectly. If the buffer does fill however, I'd like to start dropping some values (possibly using [reservoir sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) and random eviction as suggested here - [Percentiles of Live Data Capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248815/percentiles-of-live-data-capture#comment1237843_1259182)). Unfortunately I can't find a solution that works well in both scenarios - if the buffer is not full, I don't want to evict or ignore values, and once it gets full and I start evicting I invariably introduce bias.

Comment: What is the size of the buffer?

Comment: The size is configurable. Right now I have 10,000 ints = 40KB. I _could_ make it bigger but since I don't have any way of knowing how many values will be arriving - that might change considerably over time - every size I'll pick might not be enough. And simply throwing 10MB at it is too wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

OK I think I figured it out - I can use [Algorithm R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling#Relation_to_Fisher-Yates_shuffle) to uniformly select a fixed sized subset of the incoming elements. Then I can compute the percentiles from this subset.