# Better measure than "average" to highlight outlying values?

Tags: performance, math, statistics

For web app debugging purposes, I am currently showing a single number that represents the average JSON request time.

We do a large number of JSON requests, and most of them succeed quickly.  The ones that occasionally take a few seconds to complete are the real problem.  Showing the average request time is nearly useless, as the average is almost always excellent.

What kind of calculation can I do to generate a quality-of-service type of number that will go up when long request times start to become more prevalent?

Something like "max request time time in the last 5 minutes" is one way, but that doesn't give any information about how many times it happened or really how bad the problem is.

Thank you.

Comment: Sort the times and pick off the percentiles. Like if you have 100 times and pick the 50th highest one, that is the median (not precisely). The 95th highest one is the 95th percentile. You get the idea.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248815/percentiles-of-live-data-capture